# Custom Dates in Android ListView (Java Formatting)

Tags: java, android, date, android-listview

I have a `ListView` that users will put comment in.  When they hit "submit" attached to an `EditText` box, the new comment goes into a `MySQL` database along with the current time.

I'd like the comments to appear in the listview with dates similar to Youtube formatting. For example:  "10 seconds ago", "1 day ago", "52 days ago".

Would I use the Calendar object, SimpleDateFormat, something else?

Also, how would I store the date in the datebase? I am assuming something easily convertible like the UNIX date stamp maybe.  And then would it be in the ArrayAdapter where I dynamically change the date based on the current time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this you need to calculate the difference between your timestamp and current timestamp (keep them in milliseconds for simplicity). The result will be number of milliseconds "ago". Then use simple math like subtraction and division and you can get number of minutes, days, weeks and whatever-you-want.

EDIT: I use this:

```
public static final long MILLIS_PER_SECOND  = 1000;
public static final long MILLIS_PER_MINUTE  = (MILLIS_PER_SECOND * 60);
public static final long MILLIS_PER_HOUR    = (MILLIS_PER_MINUTE * 60);
public static final long MILLIS_PER_DAY     = (MILLIS_PER_HOUR * 24);
public static final long MILLIS_PER_WEEK    = (MILLIS_PER_DAY * 7);
public static final long MILLIS_PER_MONTH   = (MILLIS_PER_DAY * 30);
public static final long MILLIS_PER_YEAR    = (MILLIS_PER_MONTH * 12);
```

Note that is is not 100% correct as I (intentionally, for simplicy) made **false** assumption month is always 30 days long, which also influences `MILLIS_PER_YEAR`. But I do not really care - it's not rocket science I use these for. But you may reduce the impact by setting `MILLIS_PER_YEAR` this way:

```
public static final long MILLIS_PER_YEAR = (MILLIS_PER_DAY * (7*31 + 4*30 + 28));
```

`28` is for February, in this case you only be 1 day off on leaps years, instead of 5 days as in former version.

Comment: Ok, I understand what I need to do.  Quick last question.  If I subtract the milliseconds from when the comment was made with the millesconds NOW - how do I convert the answer either in hours or days?

Comment: I think I answered my question:   (milliseconds / (1000*60*60*24));  - going to mark you correct!

Comment: Well, there are are always 1000 millis in one second. I use constants as shown in my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PrettyTime](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/) to achieve that.

For saving time, I usually save time in millis.

Comment: +1 for the boxed solution. I do not know how flexible PrettyTime is, but if anyone is planning implementing this feature, then whole code to generate this kind of dates takes about 1-2 screens of source code max, so it's really no big deal to write this by your own.

Answer (score 0):

Try DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString to format the date for display.