# Time ago for Android/java

Tags: java, android

I am newbie to java and android. One of my android news app i am displaying the time as "7 August 2014, 8:20 am"

But I need to display it like:

```
5 mins ago    
1 hour ago    
2 days ago
```

Found many libraries such us pretty time, joda. But i dont know how to add it to my android app.
Even this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/13018647/2020685 show me.
But how to pass my date and time into it.

Any simple code to do it.

Thanks

Comment: There is a parameter long time, which will be your time I guess.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because of OP's lack of contribution to solve the issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Dates in Android ListView (Java Formatting)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253332/custom-dates-in-android-listview-java-formatting) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4216745/642706) and many many others.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13018647/1318946

Comment: This lib will help you.
https://github.com/ChathuraHettiarachchi/TimeAgo

Answer (score 49, accepted):

What you want to display is called as the Relative time display. Android provides methods 
to display time relative to your current time. You don't have to use any third party library just for this purpose.

You can use

```
DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(long time, long now, long minResolution)
```

### [Refer docs Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString(long,%20long,%20long))

eg.

```
DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(your_time_in_milliseconds, current_ time_in_millisecinds,DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
```

**UPDATE1:**

You can try following to pass your date and get the milliseconds for it.

```
public static long getDateInMillis(String srcDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat desiredFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "d MMMM yyyy, hh:mm aa");

    long dateInMillis = 0;
    try {
        Date date = desiredFormat.parse(srcDate);
        dateInMillis = date.getTime();
        return dateInMillis;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.d("Exception while parsing date. " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This is the simplest way of doing what the OP wanted to do. No extra libraries are needed, no extra code logic is needed, just an import!

Comment: Fine, but i have the time like this "7 August 2014, 8:20 am" How can i pass it to the "DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(long time, long now, long minResolution)"

Comment: you need to convert your current date "7 August 2014, 8:20 am" to milliseconds.

Comment: Tried many ways to convert "7 August 2014, 8:20 am" to milliseconds but failed. Any simple way? Thanks

Comment: I'm following your answer (DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(your_time_in_milliseconds, System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS)) & all I can see the output was "Jan 18, 1970". Can you guys help?

Comment: @Srikar, make sure the time value you are passing is in milliseconds.

Comment: @RiteshGune Thanks. That was the mistake. My time is in seconds and when I changed it to milliseconds, the issue was resolved.

Comment: ok..glad to help you.

Comment: downvoter care to comment??

Comment: It not give the time ago for me it simply returning the value as 26 Oct 2020. How can i acheive this my DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(time, System.currentTimeMillis(),DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS); my time = 1603714252000

Answer (score 6):

Create the below logic:

### Convert your time to seconds, get the diff ( delta ) from current file :

1. `% it by 3600*365`

   - if the `result > 0` then display  year(s) ago
2. `else % it by 3600 * 30`

   - if the `result > 0` then display  month(s) ago
3. `else % it by 3600 * 7`

   - if the `result > 0` then display  week(s) ago
4. `else % it by 3600`

   - if the `result > 0` then display  day(s) ago
5. `else % it by 3600 / 24`

   - if the `result > 0` then display  hour(s) ago
6. `else % it by 60`,

   - if the `result > 0` then display  minute(s) ago

**NOTE:** % means mod (modulus operation)

Answer (score 2):

```
Date nowDate=new Date();
Date yourPassDate=//you have a date here.
long now=nowDate.getTime();
long time=yourPassDate.getTime();


final long diff = now - time;  //now you have a date interval representing with mileseconds.
//you can use this diff to do something like:
if (diff <1000*60)//less than one minute
    //...
else if (diff <1000*60*60) //less than 1 hour
    //...    
else if (diff < 1000*60*60*24)//less than one day
    //...
```

This is what java doc of Date.getTime() said:

> ```
>  * Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT
>  * represented by this <tt>Date</tt> object.
> ```