# DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString not giving proper result

Tags: java, android

Currently I'm using `DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString` to get an output like.

```
8 minutes ago
8 hours ago
```

But instead it return. My code is exactly in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174921/time-ago-for-android-java)

```
In 4 hr
In 5 hr
```

Here is my code

```
long postTime = getDateInMillis(pubDate);
CharSequence time = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(System.currentTimeMillis(),postTime,DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS,DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE);
```

My  getDateInMillis method

```
 public static long getDateInMillis(String srcDate) {

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z",Locale.getDefault());

    long dateInMillis = 0;
    try {
        Date date = formatter.parse(srcDate);
        dateInMillis = date.getTime();
        return dateInMillis;
    }

    catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Please help me getting the right format that I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My silly mistake.

The reason why it happen was due to this line

```
CharSequence time = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(System.currentTimeMillis(),postTime,DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS,DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE);
```

I switched the position of `System.currentTimeMillis(),` and `postTime` then it returned the right format.